# Power BI and Azure Functions

Tags: powerbi, azure-functions

I have write a very basic azure app function.

I have one input parameter and a result (strings)

It works with Htpptrigger. I have test it in my browser. It works fine.

What i want to do is to is to call this function from a power bi report (in a DAX function for example).

Is there a way to do that ? I have read some tutorials, but it is very complex, they work with dataset. I don't want to create a new dataset for my function. I just want to call this function when i am displaying a field value in a table for example

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about something like [this](https://chris.koester.io/index.php/2017/03/28/call-an-azure-function-from-power-bi/#:%7E:text=If%20you%27re%20not%20familiar,in%20the%20specified%20time%20zone.):

```
let
    url = "https://<function app name>.azurewebsites.net",
    timezoneID = "Eastern Standard Time",
    
    // Call GetJson Power BI function to convert record to JSON object
    jsonContent = GetJson([timezone=timezoneID]),

    // Submit JSON object to Azure Function using an HTTP POST
    StatusUpdate = Web.Contents(url,
     [
         Headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/json"],
         Content = Text.ToBinary(jsonContent),
         RelativePath="/api/<function name>?code=<function code>"
     ]
 ),
response = Json.Document(StatusUpdate)
in
    response
```

Comment: I have tried to put this code in a column or in a measure i have a lot of syntax errors